# Show $(a+b, a-b) = 1$ or $2$ if $(a,b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here was my take on the proof.  We already know that since $(a,b)=1$, there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=1$.  Let $d=(a+b,a-b)$.  Then $d|(a+b)$ and $d|(a-b)$.  In particular, there exist integers $k_1, k_2$ such that 
$$a+b=dk_1$$
$$a-b=dk_2$$
Thus depending whether we add or subtract the two equation we get both
$$2a=d(k_1+k_2)$$
$$2b=d(k_1-k_2)$$
Thus, $d|2a$ and $d|2b$.  But then also 
$$d|(2ax+2by)\Rightarrow d|2(ax+by)$$
Thus, $d|2$ and thus $d=1$ or $2$.

I don't know why, but I feel like there is a problem with my argument.  Perhaps something I haven't said...I feel like it's almost there, but missing some sort of justification, but it's late and I can't figure it out....

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews.  The other page confirms what I think I needed.

Comment: Your proof is entirely correct and very nicely written.

Comment: Thank you, @WillO.  I don't know what I thought I needed, something with the (a,b)=1.  But as I mentioned, it was late and I had been up for about 20 hours.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no problem. But you can "encapsulate" your proof using rules like $$a|b,a|c\Rightarrow a|(b,c),a|mb+nc$$ So by $$d|a+b,d|a-b$$ you directly get $$d|2a, d|2b$$ and then $$d|(2a,2b)=2(a,b)=2$$

Examples for both cases exist:
$$(5,3)=1, (5-3, 5+3)=(2,8)=2$$
$$(4,3)=1, (4-3, 4+3)=(1,7)=1$$